# adding a record to database through slick scala

Tags: mysql, scala, slick

I have a table in mysql database which consists of 3 columns: ID (int and primary key), name and surname (both are strings). 
Now I created a model class in scala:

```
class Clients(
    ID: Int,
    NAME: String,
    SURNAME: String
)
```

and in main function I have this code which connects me to db:

```
val db = Database.forConfig("scalaTest")
```

and my application.conf looks like this:

```
scalaTest = {
  url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/Scala1"
  user = "root"
  password = "mysql"
  driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  connectionPool = disabled
  keepAliveConnection = true
}
```

And I am supposed to use slick framework to make connection between my scala program and database.

Now I am wondering if I created my model well, or should it look different? Also, I do not know how to connect my model class to database, I've seen few code samples (even the hello_slick_3.0 which is a demo of how to use slick for this purpose), but I did not understand those.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to define a table model. You can check a full fledged example here:
 [Gist for Slick 3.1.0 with scala](https://gist.github.com/vicpara/f79b561307a56f1c05e1).

The example is for H2(in memory database but slick abstracts the DB away. It's done exactly the same way for any underlying DB.